# linq methods or query with table and list

Tags: list, entity-framework, linq

Let a table TabA, with only 3 int columns : TabA (col1,col2,col3)

Let  a list L2int, of type list<int c1,int c2>  with several items (ex ((1,2),(2,3)....)

I want to use linq methods (or linq query second way)  to find from TabA the values of col1 where (col2,col3) is in Liste2int (col3==c3 && col2==c2).

The result should be a list of int ie List.

Thanks for your attention

Answer (score 0):

```
var ln= from c in L2int from cols in Tab2 where cols.col1==c.c1 && cols.col2==c.c2 select new {foo=cols.col3}
```

thx

I want to add that linq queries or linq methods are less performant than raw SQL (direct sql)!